# Calculating difference of rows using UDF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the difference of runs between two consecutive overs. And if possible, difference of runs between two random overs in ascending order. let's say run_calc(6, 3). The output will be difference of runs from 6th over to 3rd over
small subset of the dataframe given below

```
data = {'Overs' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],  
        'Runs' : [10, 5, 9, 5, 11, 6, 13, 9, 2, 10]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Total Runs'] = df['Runs'].cumsum()
df
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select the index and chop this certain values you are interested in and add your desired function which I don't exactly get it like this:

```
def run_calc(x, y):
    X = df[df["Overs"]==x].index.values
    Y = df[df["Overs"]==y].index.values
    df1 = df.loc[X:Y]
    # add you function here on the selected indexes in df1
    return value
```